# OpenAPI Warning: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openapi, superagent

I generate my sdk with openapi-generator with the following command :

```
docker run --network=host --rm \
        -v $(pwd)/clients:/tmp \
        openapitools/openapi-generator-cli:v{open_api_generator_version} generate \
        -i {url}/openapi.json \
        -o /tmp/{language} \
        -D modelDocs=false \
        -D apiDocs=false \
        -D apiTests=false \
        -D modelTests=false \
        -D npmVersion=3.5.2 \
        -D supportsES6=true \
        -g javascript
```

But when I call my api with the SDK it result with the following error:
`Warning: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent`

Executed code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const api = new MyApi()

    api.apiClient.basePath = 'http://localhost:8080'

    api.getMyRouteGet().then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }, [])
```

PS: I see that when I remove the following code from `ApiClient.js` it works:

```js
          request.end((error, response) => {
            if (callback) {
                var data = null;
                if (!error) {
                    try {
                        data = this.deserialize(response, returnType);
                        if (this.enableCookies && typeof window === 'undefined'){
                            this.agent._saveCookies(response);
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        error = err;
                    }
                }

                callback(error, data, response);
            }
        });
```

Do you have any idea what do I do wrong?